# Resetting nested smart pointer of a shared_ptr to a shared_ptr (or to a unique_ptr), seeming paradox

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, unique-ptr, nested

I know the object managed by a `std::shared_ptr` is not `delete`d by `reset()` unless it is the only `shared_ptr` that manages it at that point. I know that when there are multiple `shared_ptr`s managing the same object, changes to the managed object’s value are reflected through all `shared_ptr`s that point to it, while changes to any of these `shared_ptr`’s value (*not* its managed object’s value) caused by `reset()`ting it (i.e. changing the `shared_ptr` from one that points to the original managed object to one that points to nothing or something else) does not change the other `shared_ptr`s’ values (i.e. they all still point to the original managed object, and the original managed object still exists):

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<shared_ptr<int>> vec{ make_shared<int>(5) };
    shared_ptr<int> sptr(vec[0]);
    ++ *sptr;
    cout << *vec[0] << endl; // 6
    vec[0].reset();
    vec.pop_back();
    cout << *sptr << endl;   // 6
}
```

But that logic is lost to me when using two levels of indirection. Given a class named `Wrapper` and a `shared_ptr<shared_ptr<Wrapper>>` and any number of other `shared_ptr<shared_ptr<Wrapper>>`s initialized to the prior, why does this configuration allow a `reset()` called on any inner `shared_ptr` to effectively `reset()` all other inner `shared_ptr`s?

My guess is: the managed object of any of the **out**er `shared_ptr`s is the inner `shared_ptr` (not the `Wrapper`) and changes to the value of the inner `shared_ptr` (by `reset()`ting the inner `shared_ptr`, which changes the value of the inner `shared_ptr` from one that points to a `Wrapper` instance to one that points to nothing) is reflected throughout all **out**er `shared_ptr`s, effectively causing *all* **out**er `shared_ptr`s to lose indirect management over the `Wrapper` instance, thereby deleting the `Wrapper` instance.

But by the same logic, isn’t resetting one of the inner pointers only going to cause that particular inner pointer to lose management over the `Wrapper`? Given that all the other outer pointers point to inner pointers of their own (i.e. the ones that were constructed with them), wouldn’t those outer ones continue to have indirect management over the `Wrapper`, since resetting one inner pointer doesn’t change the `Wrapper`’s value, which should still be accessible by the other inner pointers? It’s a paradox to me.

If resetting one inner pointer effectively resets all of them, then that means the inner pointers' `use_count()` was `1` right before the `reset()`. The only way I thought multiple `shared_ptr`s can *appear* to manage the same object while keeping `use_count()` at `1` would be through illusion: they manage different objects (i.e. objects at different addresses) that have the same value. I tested this by making an `int` wrapper named `Wrapper`, whose only data members are the wrapped `int` and a `static` `instance_count` that keeps track of the number of `Wrapper` instances that currently exist.

```
struct Wrapper {
    Wrapper(int par = 0) : num(par) { ++instance_count; }
    Wrapper(const Wrapper& src) : num(src.num) { ++instance_count; }
    ~Wrapper() { --instance_count; }
    int num;
    static int instance_count;
};
int Wrapper::instance_count = 0;

int main() {
    shared_ptr<shared_ptr<Wrapper>> dual_ptr_1(
        make_shared<shared_ptr<Wrapper>>(
            make_shared<Wrapper>(Wrapper(5))
        )
    );
                                                            // - Output -
    cout << Wrapper::instance_count << endl;                // 1
    shared_ptr<shared_ptr<Wrapper>> dual_ptr_2(dual_ptr_1);
    cout << Wrapper::instance_count << endl;                // 1
    cout << dual_ptr_1->use_count() << endl;                // 1
    cout << dual_ptr_2->use_count() << endl;                // 1
    cout << dual_ptr_1.use_count() << endl;                 // 2
    cout << dual_ptr_2.use_count() << endl;                 // 2
    // note that above, the '->' operator accesses
    // inner ptr while '.' operator is for outer ptr
    cout << (*dual_ptr_1)->num << endl;                     // 5
    cout << (*dual_ptr_2)->num << endl;                     // 5
    dual_ptr_2->reset();
    cout << Wrapper::instance_count << endl;                // 0
    cout << dual_ptr_1->use_count() << endl;                // 0
    cout << dual_ptr_2->use_count() << endl;                // 0
    cout << dual_ptr_1.use_count() << endl;                 // 2
    cout << dual_ptr_2.use_count() << endl;                 // 2
}
```

Apparently there were `2` inner pointers that point to `1` `Wrapper` object; the inner pointers' `use_count` was at most `1` (prior to destruction); the `Wrapper` class's `instance_count` was at most `1` (prior to destruction); and the indirectly managed `Wrapper` object was accessible through both outer pointers (which means neither outer pointer got move-constructed by the other); and resetting one inner pointer effectively reset all of them; so I still don't understand the seeming paradox.

I'm also asking the same questions in this post about the case in which the above code has the inner `shared_ptr`s replaced by `unique_ptr`s, the inner `make_shared` replaced by `make_unique`, and the `use_count()` commented out for the inner pointers (because `unique_ptr`s lack that method), which gives the same output. That's a seeming paradox to me because the `unique_ptr`s don't seem unique here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you were expecting, `dual_ptr_1` and `dual_ptr_2` both share ownership of the single inner `shared_ptr` , which in turn manages a single instance of `Wrapper`. `dual_ptr_2->reset();` destroys the single `Wrapper` instance so you're left with shared ownership of an empty `shared_ptr`.

Comment: As everyone else is saying. Think of it like this: `Wrapper * w = new Wrapper(); Wrapper ** a = &w; Wrapper ** b = &w; delete *a; *a = nullptr;` <-- Would you be surprised that `*b` is now null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Given a class named `Wrapper` and a `shared_ptr<shared_ptr<Wrapper>>` and
>   any number of other `shared_ptr<shared_ptr<Wrapper>>`s initialized to
>   the prior, why does this configuration allow a `reset()` called on any
>   inner shared_ptr to effectively `reset()` all other inner `shared_ptrs`?

There are no other inner `shared_ptr`s, you have a single instance of the contained object, i.e.

```
dual_ptr_1
          \
           --> shared_ptr --> Wrapper
          /
dual_ptr_2
```

And not

```
dual_ptr_1 --> shared_ptr 
                         \
                          --> Wrapper
                         /
dual_ptr_2 --> shared_ptr
```

After your call to `dual_ptr_2->reset();` this changes to

```
dual_ptr_1
          \
           --> shared_ptr --> (empty)
          /
dual_ptr_2
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer shows with a diagram what happens in the OP code: two outer `shared_ptr`s point to the same inner `shared_ptr`, which points to the `Wrapper` object. (I refer to the diagrams in the unedited version of the accepted answer; it hasn’t been edited at the time of my answer here.) The accepted answer has another diagram, which shows what the OP expected to happen but didn’t happen, which I refer to as:

**Case A** – two outer pointers that point to different inner pointers that point to the same `Wrapper` object (refer to accepted answer for diagram).

Here’s code that causes Case A:

```
int main() {
    shared_ptr<shared_ptr<Wrapper>> dual_ptr_1(
        make_shared<shared_ptr<Wrapper>>(make_shared<Wrapper>(5))
    );
    shared_ptr<shared_ptr<Wrapper>> dual_ptr_2(
        make_shared<shared_ptr<Wrapper>>(*dual_ptr_1)
    );
    cout << dual_ptr_1.use_count() << endl;  // 1
    cout << dual_ptr_2.use_count() << endl;  // 1
    cout << dual_ptr_1->use_count() << endl; // 2
    cout << dual_ptr_2->use_count() << endl; // 2
}
```

I refer to `dual_ptr_1` as the first outer pointer and the `shared_ptr` to which it points as the first inner pointer. I refer to `dual_ptr_2` as the second outer pointer and the `shared_ptr` to which it points as the second inner pointer. The two outer pointers point to different inner pointers. The second outer pointer was not copy-constructed or assigned to the first outer pointer, so either outer pointer’s `use_count` is `1`. The second outer pointer does not point to the first inner pointer, but rather a nameless inner pointer that's copy-constructed from the first inner pointer. While the second outer pointer is still managing the second inner pointer, the latter’s namelessness doesn’t cause the latter to go out of scope. The second inner pointer points to the same `Wrapper` as the first inner pointer, because the second inner pointer was copy-constructed from the first inner pointer. Because of this `shared_ptr` copy-construction, either inner pointer’s `use_count` is `2`. Each inner pointer must be `reset()` to nothing or something else, assigned to something else, or go out of scope in order for the `Wrapper` to be destroyed (the inner pointers don’t both need to go through the same operation as long as each one goes through at least one of them).

Here’s another one, **Case B** – same diagram as Case A, but with a buggy implementation and different console output:

```
int main() {
    shared_ptr<shared_ptr<Wrapper>> dual_ptr_1(
        make_shared<shared_ptr<Wrapper>>(make_shared<Wrapper>(5))
    );
    shared_ptr<shared_ptr<Wrapper>> dual_ptr_2(
        make_shared<shared_ptr<Wrapper>>(&(**dual_ptr_1))
    ); // (*)
    cout << dual_ptr_1.use_count() << endl;  // 1
    cout << dual_ptr_2.use_count() << endl;  // 1
    cout << dual_ptr_1->use_count() << endl; // 1
    cout << dual_ptr_2->use_count() << endl; // 1
} // <- Double free runtime error at closing brace.

// Replacing line (*) with:
// shared_ptr<shared_ptr<Wrapper>> dual_ptr_2(
//     new shared_ptr<Wrapper>(&(**dual_ptr_1))
// );
// has much the same effect, possibly just without compiler optimization.
```

Case B is a buggy variation of Case A, where the difference in Case B is that the second inner pointer is constructed from a raw pointer to the `Wrapper` object rather than copy-constructed or assigned from the first inner pointer. Because of this, either inner pointer’s `use_count` stays at `1` (instead of `2`) even though they both point to the same address. So, each of these inner pointers behave as if it is the only one that manages the `Wrapper` object. A double free runtime error occurs at `main()`’s closing brace, because the last inner pointer to go out of scope is trying to free memory already freed by the previous inner pointer's going out of scope.

Here's **Case C** - two outer pointers point to different inner pointers that point to different `Wrapper` objects:

```
int main() {
    shared_ptr<shared_ptr<Wrapper>> dual_ptr_1(
        make_shared<shared_ptr<Wrapper>>(make_shared<Wrapper>(5))
    );
    shared_ptr<shared_ptr<Wrapper>> dual_ptr_2(
        make_shared<shared_ptr<Wrapper>>(make_shared<Wrapper>(**dual_ptr_1))
    );
    cout << dual_ptr_1.use_count() << endl;  // 1
    cout << dual_ptr_2.use_count() << endl;  // 1
    cout << dual_ptr_1->use_count() << endl; // 1
    cout << dual_ptr_2->use_count() << endl; // 1
}
```

Although the `Wrapper` objects have the same value, they are different objects and they are at different addresses. The second inner pointer's `Wrapper` object was copy constructed from the first inner pointer's `Wrapper` object.